# Mongoid adding user info to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, mongoid

I'm using rails 4 with mongoid and a devise gem. I added some fields in user.rb.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  field :profile_name,      :type => String
  field :type,              :type => String
  field :gender,            :type => String
  field :location,          :type => String
  field :about,             :type => String
  ...
end
```

I also edited registration and edit forms:

```
<div><%= f.label :profile_name %><br />
<%= f.text_field :profile_name, :autofocus => true %></div>

<div><%= f.label :type %><br />
<%= f.text_field :type, :autofocus => true %></div>

<div><%= f.label :gender %><br />
<%= f.select :gender, options_for_select(%w[Male Female]), :prompt => "Select your gender" %></div>
```

But it only saves standart information as: email and password. I thought of adding strong _params, but there is no user_controller.rb in my project folder.

[image: No user_controller.rb]

And server crushes and won't start even if i add:

```
gem 'strong_parameters'
```

in the gemfile. I don't know what's my problem. Otherwise, I can add posts and they're stored ok.

Comment: Rails 4 uses strong params by default.

Comment: Reading the documentation goes a long way. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/#strong-parameters

Comment: PS: @sevenseacat you helped me alot IRC, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you read through Devise fully with Rails 4. You need to setup strong params in the `application_controller.rb`

Rails 4 uses strong_params by default so there is no need to try and install it. You will need to add the attributes you require depending on the way you do it in the application_controller.rb

Just like sevencats said:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Read the documentation and understand how devise works, it can cause alot of pain if you don't really understand what is going on.

I would suggest trying to build a system from scratch first using this tutorial:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

He goes through a full user system from scratch.

Comment: Thanks! it Really hlped. And if i got questions further i'll look at this book first.